# Variable address varies weather we diplay it or not?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, buffer-overflow

Can anyone explain this?

Consider this program. We write modify `dest[10]` intentionally in order to see `j` value modified.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char source[] = "Hello";
    int j = 100;
    char dest[10];
    dest[12] = 'A';
    printf("j   = %d \n", j);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("j   = %d \n", j);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("*j   = %p \n", &j);   // comment this line to get another result!
    return 0;
}
```

output :

```
j   = 4259940
j   = 4259940
*j   = 0x7ffcc4cdef74
```

But if we comment the line displaying `j` varibale address `printf("*j   = %p \n", &j);` we get:

```
j   = 100
j   = 100
```

It is like `j` is stored elsewhere, not just after `dest` variable as in the first example.

Any explanation?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this but if I had to take a guess it's because `j` is optimized out and just replaced with a constant `100` when you don't print its address.

Comment: Decompiling (or better yet, using godbolt.org) is a good way to look at this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where and whether to store the objects `j` and `dest` and how to handle the out-of-bounds access in `dest[10]` is the compiler’s choice. Modern compilers do many complicated things to optimize programs. When you omit the statement that prints the address of `j`, the compiler makes different choices, and these produce different results.

Answer (score 1):

A variable is not required to have any storage address if the address is not taken.
The compiler is free to only hold the value in a register or completely remove it via optimization mechanisms and only use the constant value `100` directly.

You might check if you corrupted `dest` instead when `j` is not stored on the stack.